# How to discard any incoming data in a connection in Go?

Tags: go

I’m sending a request to a remote server, but don’t care about its response. I don’t want to close the connection directly because the server gets a `Broken pipe` error if I do that.

I currently loop on Read() calls with a buffer:

```
con, _ := net.Dial("tcp", host)

// ...

data := make([]byte, 512)
for {
    if _, err = con.Read(data); err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
}
```

But I’m looking for something like `>/dev/null` in Bash. I’ve found [`ioutils.Discard`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#pkg-variables), but it’s an `io.Writer` and `con.Read` only works on a `[]byte` buffer.

Is there a more efficient way than just reading in a buffer like what I’m currently doing?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you have to use `ioutil.Discard` like this

```
io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, con)
```

`io.Copy` copies from a src `io.Reader` to a `io.Writer`

`func Copy(dst Writer, src Reader) (written int64, err error)`

*io.Reader* is an interface defined as

```
type Reader interface {
        Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

*io.Writer*

```
type Writer interface {
        Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

`net.Conn` implements `io.Reader` and `ioutil.Discard` implements `io.Writer`

Comment: To elaborate: `net.Conn` implements the `io.Writer` interface. As such, it can be passed into anything which expects `io.Writer`. This includes the `io.Copy` function.

Comment: `ioutil.Discard` is Deprecated as of Go 1.16, you should use `io.Discard` instead.

Answer (score 11):

Since Go 1.16 (Feb 2021), programs should be using `io.Discard`:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "io"
)

func main() {
   fmt.Fprint(io.Discard, "hello world")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/io#Discard